# How to remove a trailing CRLF from a file?

Tags: linux, shell-script, busybox

I have a binary file with a trailing CRLF (2 bytes total) that I want to remove. How should I do it?
Please note that I'm using busybox and I don't have perl.

Comment: Is it trailing each line, or only the end of the file?

Comment: Only at the end of file. Any other CRLF should be ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a typical BusyBox installation, I think you're going to have to parse the output of `ls` to get the size. Once you have the size, extract the first n-2 bytes of the file with `head`.

```
size=$(ls -Lnd -- "$file" | awk 'NR==1 {print $5}')
head -c "$(($size - 2))" <"$file" >"$file.new"
```

If you want to truncate the file in place, use `dd`.

```
size=$(ls -Lnd -- "$file" | awk 'NR==1 {print $5}')
dd if=/dev/null of="$file" bs="$(($size - 2))" seek=1
```

Comment: Rather than parsing `ls`, busybox often has `stat` features compiled in.  If that's the case here, use `size=$(busybox stat -c '%s' "$file")` or just `size=$(stat -c '%s' "$file")` instead.

Comment: Wouldn't `wc -c < "$file"` be an easier and safer way to get the file size than parsing `ls`?  Or is `wc` often left out of busybox?

Comment: @CraigSanders `stat` is good if it's included, but it isn't always included. I chose commands with a high likelihood of being included. For example, my router doesn't have `stat`.

Comment: @jw013 `wc` in BusyBox reads the whole file and counts the bytes (unlike GNU coreutils and IIRC *BSD, which optimize `wc <foo` and `wc foo` to read the file size with `stat(2)`).

Answer (score 4):

Get the size of the file, substract two. You obtain `$n` (like with `n=$(wc -c < the-file)`) and run

```
dd bs=1 seek="$n" < /dev/null of=the-file
```

Or if you have a `truncate` that supports negative offsets (meaning offsets from the end of the file):

```
truncate  -s -2 the-file
```

Or with `ksh93`:

```
: 1<>; the-file >#((EOF-2))
```

(the `<>;` is a special form of the `<>` standard redirection operator that truncates the file after the command (here `:`) returns if it succeeded, `>#((...))` is a seek operator).

Comment: He's using `busybox` so `truncate` is probably not there. But `dd` probably is, and I like that solution *if* there's only one line in the file, or the `CFLF` is *only* at the end of the file.

Answer (score -2):

```
tr -d '\013' < input > output
```

Comment: This would delete all vertical tabs in the file, not a trailing CRLF